# WordPress SQL Custom Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

WordPress SQL Custom Query To Get Post, Post Meta Data, Category and Featured Image of the post.

I've tried so far the below code and got the post and post meta data. Now taxonomy and featured image remaining:

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT wp_posts.ID
     , wp_posts.post_title
     , mt1.meta_value as latitude
     , mt2.meta_value as longitude
     , mt3.meta_value as full_adddress
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key='lv_listing_lat')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id AND mt2.meta_key='lv_listing_lng')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id AND mt3.meta_key='_address')
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'lv_listing'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
AND ((mt1.meta_key = 'lv_listing_lat') OR (mt2.meta_key = 'lv_listing_lng' ) OR (mt3.meta_key = '_address' ))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC ");
```

Revised code by myself. In this code category achieved, now only featured image attachment url needed.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ID, post_title
, post_content
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'lv_listing_lat' AND wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID) AS "lv_listing_lat"
,(SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'lv_listing_lng' AND wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID) AS "lv_listing_lng"
,(SELECT group_concat(wp_terms.name separator ', ') 
    FROM wp_terms
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy on wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr on wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE taxonomy= 'listing_category' and wp_posts.ID = wpr.object_id
) AS "Listing Category"
,(SELECT group_concat(wp_terms.name separator ', ') 
    FROM wp_terms
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy on wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr on wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE taxonomy= 'listing_location' and wp_posts.ID = wpr.object_id
) AS "Listing Location"
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'lv_listing' 
ORDER BY
post_title
, post_content
```

Comment: Why not **$posts = get_posts(['post_type' = 'lv_listing']);** then in a foreach per post- **$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);**, **$category = get_terms($post->ID);** and **$img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);**. This seems an extremely complicated way to get three things readily available in WP

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with Dan. Your approach seems just fine to me - and (unless I've misunderstood) surely faster than the alternative (one round trip to the database, instead of many). But for further help with your problem, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Because i needed entire array of above mentioned things.

Comment: I've added some latest code written by me..now only featured image attachment url need.

Comment: That looks like a step backwards :-(

Comment: I got the query to get featured image but don't know how to merge with above query:  SELECT p.guid FROM wp_postmeta AS pm INNER JOIN wp_posts AS p ON pm.meta_value=p.ID WHERE pm.post_id =13358 AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id'